# Cannot get value from DateEntry widget in tkinter window. - object has no attribute 'get_date'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttkwidgets

My problem is I want to get the value of the date that was selected in the ttk.DateEntry widget.
According to this documentation you need to use get_date() [Docs](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html?highlight=get#tkcalendar.DateEntry.get_date)

It may be that I am misunderstanding the usage of that but I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute 'get_date'

I do use this library for styling [ttkboostrap](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/installation/)

Here is my code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

##setup the window
pwin = ttk.Window(themename="cyborg")
pwin.title('test')
    
##function to get the date
def seedate():
    print(cal.get_date())
    
##this is he DateEntry widget
cal =  ttk.DateEntry(pwin,bootstyle="info")
cal.place(x=10, y=80)

#button to get the selected date
btnpt = ttk.Button(pwin, text="Save Schedule", bootstyle="light-outline", command=seedate)
btnpt.place(x=10, y=140)

pwin.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document link is about `tkcalendar.DateEntry`, however your code uses `DateEntry` from `ttkbootstrap` module instead of `tkcalendar` module.

To get the date from `ttkbootstrap.DateEntry`, you need to get the content from the internal `Entry` widget using `.get()`:

```py
def seedate():
    print(cal.entry.get())
```